# WIndows Live ID OAuth2 Redirect Issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth-2.0, windows-live-id

I am attempting to incorporate Windows Live ID in my application.

[image]

First, I created a Windows Live Dev Application account, here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive

Let's pretend my Client ID is 12345 (of course, it's really quite longer)

Then, I followed these instructions:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx

This suggests the following sample URL:

> > https://oauth.live.com/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPES&response_type=token&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL

I use this custom URL:

> https://oauth.live.com/authorize?client_id=12345&response_token=token&scope=wl.signin%2cwl.basic%2cwl.offline_access&redirect_url=https%3a%2f%2foauth.live.com&display=touch

Horray, the user get's prompted to login!

Boo, the user is redirected to an invalid page.

Is there something I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was in my URL, of course. The correct would be:

> > https://oauth.live.com/authorize?client_id=12345&response_type=token&scope=wl.signin%2cwl.basic%2cwl.offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2foauth.live.com%2fdesktop&display=touch

Hope this helps someone else trying to figure this out!